# overflow-x not working on smaller resolutions or mobile devices

Tags: html, css

In [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oveflow-x-not-working-on-smaller-resoutions-j7x7uz?file=/index.html) and in the html and css in this question, I am setting up my HTML for an animation (not included).  I have set one of the div's width to 500% and 'oveflow-x` to hidden on the body tag.

In order to view this bug you need to be in chrome devtool's mobile veiw.

The `overflow-x` works well until I view it on a mobile device or in mobile view in chrome devtools where it is possible to scroll right.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

#panels #panels-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#panels #panels-container .panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.full-screen {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.breaking {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="h-full m-0 p-0">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>overflow-x</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <main>
        <section class="intro"><h1>Intro</h1></section>
        <section id="panels">
          <div id="panels-container" style="width: 500%;">
            <article class="panel">
              <div class="breaking">
                <div class="left">left</div>
                <div class="right">right</div>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h1>Panel 2</h1>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h1>Panel 3</h1>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h2>Panel 4</h2>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h2>Panel 5</h2>
            </article>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="map" class="full-screen"><h1>End</h1></section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your codesandbox link is not working, can you check and update the link ?

Comment: it works for me, what is the error.

Alternatively, you can click full page in the snippet in the post.

Comment: I had to allow 3rd party cookies for codesandbox, so it could be that.  The snippet in the question might be easier

Comment: I get error Sandbox not found, but no worries I have created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/hco26ymk/3/), btw where have you added `overflow-x` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have added `overflow: hidden;` to the `#panels-container`, Just add `overflow-x: scroll;` or `overflow-x: auto;` to the `#panels`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

#panels {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#panels #panels-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#panels #panels-container .panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.full-screen {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.breaking {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="h-full m-0 p-0">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>overflow-x</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <main>
        <section class="intro"><h1>Intro</h1></section>
        <section id="panels">
          <div id="panels-container" style="width: 500%;">
            <article class="panel">
              <div class="breaking">
                <div class="left">left</div>
                <div class="right">right</div>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h1>Panel 2</h1>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h1>Panel 3</h1>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h2>Panel 4</h2>
            </article>
            <article class="panel">
              <h2>Panel 5</h2>
            </article>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="map" class="full-screen"><h1>End</h1></section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/hco26ymk/5/).